# what is the different between " to bean" and "ref bean" in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

in camel , what is the different between doing

```
<route>
   <from uri="direct:start"/>
   <to uri="bean:helloBean" />
</route>
```

and

```
<route>
   <from uri="direct:start"/>
   <bean ref="helloBean" method="hello"/>
</route>
```

is the binding the same ? when should I use each ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately there is no difference as both of them ends up calling a bean.

The first one is using a Camel component/endpoint so you can use that anywhere where you can specify an endpoint, eg in other EIPs such as `<recipientList>`, `<wireTap>` etc.

The latter is an explicit bean method call. This may stand out a bit more because the XML tag is named `bean`, and also you can specify the name of the method in the XML attribute named `method`.

If you had to specify the name of the method in the former, you would need to specify that in the uri, eg `bean:helloBean?method=hello`.

And yes the bean binding is the same. When to use what is your decision. Some people prefer just doing Camel routes that are dominantly just from -> to -> to -> to etc.

Comment: Is there a difference between the two when using Camel in an OSGi environment, and the bundle that contains the bean is stopped, uninstalled, installed and restarted?